# T-SQL - Average Per Group

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms-2016

In SSMS, I have an `Orders` fact table which looks like this:

**Orders**

```
ID   GroupKey    OrderID    Amount    DaysKey
----------------------------------------------
1    29          29422      23.93      14
2    29          29444     -13.28     101
3    29          29453      14.28     101
4    30          30194     100.00     103
5    32          30201     101.53      93
6    32          30291      50.00     121
```

I have a `Groups` dimension which looks like this

**Groups**

```
Key    Name           StyleKey       AvgXX
-------------------------------------------
29     Blue           2              NULL
30     xyz            1              NULL
31     doesntmatter   2              NULL
32     Red            1              NULL
```

I have a `Days` dimension which looks like this:

**Days**

```
    Key    Day
    ------------ 
    1      0
    2      1 
    3      4
    ...    ...
    1000   999
```

I have a `Style` dimension which looks like this:

**Style**

```
Key     Style
---------------
1       3.5
2       2
```

What I am trying to do is populate the `[AvgXX]` column on the `Groups` table with the average `Amount` for each `Style` where the `Day` is greater than or equal to 100.

So for example, the `Red` group is of `StyleKey 1`. There are 2 entries in the `Orders` table that are for `StyleKey 1` and are greater than 100 days (see records 4 and 6). Therefore, the `AvgXX` column for the `Red` group should be 75.00.

The average for the `Blue` group (Group 29) should be 1, because 1) there is only 1 group with StyleKey 1 on the Orders table (see rows 2 and 3) and the total Amount for DayKey 101 is 1 (and the first row has a Day of less than 100 so it should be ignored).

Further, I want the average per Style (currently there are only 2 Styles)

Typically, I would do a calculation like this in a visualization tool, but in this case, sadly, I cannot.

Comment: Should blue's avg 0.5 instead of 1?

Comment: No, 101 is the same day so it should only be divided by 1 day

Comment: It seems like you have a bunch of criteria here.  Maybe if you provide the code that you attempted we could help you dial it in but this is not very clear what is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this

```
Select GroupKey
     , Average(Amount) OVER (Partition By GroupKey)
FROM Orders
WHERE Day >= 100
GROUP BY GroupKey
```

If you want to see the averages of each group key.

Answer (score 0):

```
select StyleKey, avg(Amount) 'awb' 
from groups 
join orders
  on orders.ID = groups.key 
 and DaysKey >= 101
```

you are going to need to figure out how to sum by day
this is not a coding service